# Is there an R function for checking if files with a certain extension exist in a path?

Tags: r

I have a function which imports all .csv files that exist on a given path. 
However, i need a way to check if any .csv files exist in the path at all.

I tried using file.exists("*.csv$") but it gives me incorrect results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using base R:

```r
list.files(path = "pathname", pattern = "\\.csv$")
```

will return a vector of strings with the filenames that end in ".csv". To check if any exist, use:

```r
length(list.files(path = "pathname", pattern = "\\.csv$")) > 0
```

Comment: How to check with multiple extensions? `.csv, .txt, .rds` etc...